# Group rows in data.frame and find quantile

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, rows, quantile

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(789)
df_1 = data.frame(a = 22, b = 24, c = rnorm(10))
df_2 = data.frame(a = 44, b = 24, c = rnorm(10))
df_3 = data.frame(a = 33, b = 99, c = rnorm(10))

df_all = rbind(df_1, df_2, df_3)
```

I need to group `df_all` by column `a` and `b`, and then find the 50th quantile based on column `c`.

This can be done singularly, for each `df`, as follows:

```
df_1_q = quantile(df_1$c, probs = 0.50)
df_2_q = quantile(df_2$c, probs = 0.50)
df_3_q = quantile(df_3$c, probs = 0.50)
```

However my real `df_all` is larger than this.

And more generally, how can I group a `data.frame` by rows and apply a given function?

thanks

Comment: `tapply()` can do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462610/groupwise-computation-in-r

Comment: Or use `aggregate(c ~ a + b, df_all, median)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` for that

```
library(dplyr)
df_all %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  summarise(quantile = quantile(c, probs = 0.5))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   a [?]
      a     b quantile
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1    22    24   -0.268
2    33    99   -0.234
3    44    24   -0.445
```

Or using `data.table` as:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df_all)
dt[,list(quantile=quantile(c, probs = 0.5)),by=c("a", "b")]
    a  b       quantile
1: 22 24 -0.2679104
2: 44 24 -0.4450979
3: 33 99 -0.2336712
```

Comment: 50th quantile is the median, so `median` would probably be a lot faster

Comment: yes, but the user can have any percentile that he may want to use.